# Face Retopology in 2.8

Tags: modifiers

guys

A quick question: I am retopologising a sculpt I made. However, the single issue I have is when I attempt to move a vertex of the new mesh, the whole thing moves. How do I "unlink" the mesh so it doesn't all move when I try to reposition a single vertex?

I did a mirror modifier//then shrinkwrap. I don't see a setting tht could stop this happening.

Thanks,

P

Comment: have you enabled the proportional editing option? Also, I know some use the shrinkwrap but I think snap should work for retopology

Comment: Oh, god! Yes, that's all I needed to do. 

The frustrating bit about being completely new to 3D is I do not even know the names of operations which makes it difficult to even Google a solution because, essentially, I do not know what to Google. So I've looked online for the last week and could not fix it. THANK YOU SO MUCH @moonboots!